# JSON with Array Respone from API

Tags: c#, arrays, json, rest, httpclient

i have a HTTPclient and im sending request to a Server.
The response from the server is a JSON. In this Json is also an array.
I want do display the information from the JSON in the consol.
I get all information from the JSON, but i dont get the array displayed in my console.

The JSON looks like this:

```
{
    "Name1": "Karl",
    "Name2": "Peter",
    "Name3": "Wilhelm",
    "PreNames": {
        "PreName": "Werner",
        "PreName2": "Josef"
    }
}
```

So now my Code so far:

```
public class PreNames //for Array
    {
        public string PreName { get; set; }
        public string PreName2{ get; set; }
    }

    public class Names//for JSON
    {
        public string Name1{ get; set; }
        public string Name2{ get; set; }
        public string Name3{ get; set; }
    }
```

And my Main:

```
if (Response().IsSuccessStatusCode)
        {
            var namesJ= Response().Content.ReadAsAsync<IEnumerable<Names>>().Result;
            var preNamesJ= await Response().Content.ReadAsAsync<List<PreNames>>();



            foreach (var a in namesJ)

            {

                Console.WriteLine("Name1: {0}", a.Name1);

                foreach(var b in preNamesJ)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("{0}", b.PreName);
                }
                
            }
```

So in the console are all names displayed, but not the PreNames so i cant get the PreNames from the array in the JSON...

I Hope somebody could help me :)

Comment: add proper JSON this one seems not valid

Comment: how i do that ? :/

Comment: I your Main async ? If not, you might want to remove the await keyword and add a .Result() at the end of the line. If it is, you should remove the .Result(), and add an await keyword at the right of the "="

Comment: the Method for the JSON is normal, but the Method for the array is Async. also not worked

Comment: the comment on the async, .Result() looks correct

the json, if that is exactly what you are getting back is invalid, its should be something like:

{
 "Name1": "Karl",
 "Name2": "Peter",
 "Name3": "Wilhelm",
 "PreNames": [
  { "PreName": "Werner" },
  { "PreName2": "Josef" }
 ]
}

You cannot have a json object array without putting the key/value pairs in {...}

Comment: yes, but this is a valid JSON.. Its the response from the Server. The JSON in my question was written by hand and was an example. My original JSON is valid, but the syntax is equal to my example

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Leonc443, Here is a working code

```
    using Newtonsoft.Json;  //add this nuget package
    using System;

    namespace ConsoleApp
    {
        class Program
        {
            public static void Main(string[] args)
            {
                string json = @"{
                    'Name1': 'Karl',
                    'Name2': 'Peter',
                    'Name3': 'Wilhelm',
                    'PreNames': {
                                'PreName': 'Werner',
                                'PreName2': 'Josef'
                            }
                }";  // data received from api
                var names = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Names>(json);
                Console.WriteLine(names.Name1);     // Karl
                Console.WriteLine(names.Name2);     //Peter
                Console.WriteLine(names.Name3);     //Wilhelm
                Console.WriteLine(names.PreNames.PreName);      //Werner
                Console.WriteLine(names.PreNames.PreName2);     // Josef

            }
        }
        public class Names
        {
            public string Name1 { get; set; }
            public string Name2 { get; set; }
            public string Name3 { get; set; }
            public PreNames PreNames { get; set; }
        }

        public class PreNames
        {
            public string PreName { get; set; }
            public string PreName2 { get; set; }
        }
    }
```

Please let me know if this helps

Answer (score 1):

Add the PreNames property to your Names class and only read one time.

```
public class Names//for JSON
    {
        public string Name1{ get; set; }
        public string Name2{ get; set; }
        public string Name3{ get; set; }
        public List<PreNames> PreNames { get; set;}
    }
```

Once you read in the result one time, you can access the elements via the main object

```
var namesJ= Response().Content.ReadAsAsync<Names>().Result;
foreach(var names in namesJ.PreNames)
{
  Console.WriteLine(names.PreName);
}
```

**updated**
Since you changed the json and made PreNames just an object instead of an array, simply access the property of related object.

```
public class Names//for JSON
    {
        public string Name1{ get; set; }
        public string Name2{ get; set; }
        public string Name3{ get; set; }
        public PreNames PreNames { get; set;}
    }

var namesJ= Response().Content.ReadAsAsync<Names>().Result;
Console.WriteLine(namesJ.PreNames.Name);
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't have sufficient reputation to comment, so... I'll give it a try.

Edited after proper json updated in Answer.

1. Change your class Names

```
public class Names
{
    public string Name1 { get; set; }
    public string Name2 { get; set; }
    public string Name3 { get; set; }
    public PreNames PreNames { get; set; }
}
```

2. Then deserialize it with JsonConvert

```
var json = await Response().Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
var names = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Names>(json);
```

3. Then access data

```
Console.WriteLine($"Name 1: {names.Name1}");
Console.WriteLine($"Prename 1: {names.PreNames.PreName}");
```

Comment: the "name.PreNames?.PreName" doesnt work... after PreName?, i am not able to choose the PreName

Comment: If you mouseover name from (var name in names) in debug mode, you should see Name1, Name2, Name3 and PreNames. I added the ? just in case the value (PreNames) is null which seems to be the case.

Could you please clarify what exactly is that part of the original json you receive?

Comment: when i mouseover, i can see that in "json" is the whole response, but "name" is null. and the ? is also added

Comment: Just saw you edited the first json, so here it is (I will update my answer too): https://dotnetfiddle.net/9EG8WK

Answer (score 0):

In case your Json looks like:

```
{
    "Name1": "Karl",
    "Name2": "Peter",
    "Name3": "Wilhelm",
    "PreNames": {
        "PreName": "Werner",
        "PreName2": "Josef"
    }
}
```

---

If the PreNames are in the Names, you shuld add a `PreNames` field to the `Names` Class.

```
public class Names
{
    public string Name1 { get; set; }
    public string Name2 { get; set; }
    public string Name3 { get; set; }
    public PreNames PreNames { get; set; }
}
```

Then you can read the inner PreNames:

```
foreach (var b in a.Prenames) {
    Console.WriteLine(b.PreName);
}
```

But I'm not sure if I understand your question.